# We changed order for a list, now we need a mechanism for accessing elements by index with matching behaviour

Tags: python

There is a class BaseFormSet.

```
class BaseFormSet(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.forms)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.forms[index]
```

Where self.forms is a list. In the documentation they tell us that this class represents a set of forms, the order being in the order they were created. And we can change order: we have to override __iter__() method of BaseFormSet. But if we override __iter__(), we will need to also override __getitem__() to have matching behavior.

Well, this __getitem__() astonishes me a bit.

Well, we are talking about lists, as a matter of fact. So, in the example I'll use a list.

This is what I can think of to the best of my ability:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // Imitating a formset.

def get_reversed_index(length, index):
    return -(index+1) % length


def print_result(i):
    reversed_index = get_reversed_index(len(l), i)
    return "Index {}, reversed {}, reversed value {}".format(i, reversed_index, l[reversed_index])
```

This seems to reverse the index. But is it a matching behavior which documentation implies?

What troubles me: myMy code seems unable to raise IndexError exception.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
In case of ordinary 
print(l[10])
```

Could you help me: what matching behavour is necessary? And whether my example is garbage?

P.S. The class is from Django.

Comment: "But is it a matching behavior which documentation implies?" what do you mean by this and what documentation are you referring to?

Comment: Well, the Django documentation from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/. But that doesn't matter: I tried to quote what is necessary. We change a list order. Then we should change method for accessing by index. Maybe I should raise exception myself?

Comment: Right. I think your question would be a _lot_ clearer if you removed the parts that don't matter - i.e. all the Django form code and discussion and just asked about how to generate the list indices. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for next time!

Comment: What's astonishing about the `__getitem__` method?

Comment: Just guessing what you are asking for. Maybe you should delegate directly: `def __iter__(self): return self.forms.__iter__()` (same for `__getitem__`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question, but if you mean that you *want* to raise an exception from your "reversed" indices, then you need to change your `get_reversed_index` function.

Currently, the output of this function is guaranteed to be in the range `[0, length)` due to the `%` or mod operator. So if you want to generate indices that can be out of bounds, try removing the `% length` ...

Comment: Removing the `% length`won't provide the same exact output (as if for any reason the OP dont want negative index) so I would probably suggest to check the length first : `if index >= length: raise IndexError` before returning the index : `return -(index+1) % length`.

Comment: Negative indexing is also possible. Maybe         if index not in range(-length, length): raise IndexError